# Can't initialize variable

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Assignment3 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   double width;
   double length;
   double height;
   double weight;
   double totalDimen;         // (width * length * height) + weight
   double shipping;
   double totalCost;
   double cost12 = 12;
   double cost14 = 14;
   double cost17 = 17;
   double cost21 = 21;
   double cost33 = 33;
   double cost105 = 105;
   double surcharge;
   int zipCode;               //gets the zip code
   char zipCode2;

   String input;

   //changing the decimal format
   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");


   //getting weight
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total weight");
   weight = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting height
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total height");
   height = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting length
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total length");
   length = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting width
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total width");
   width = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting zipCode
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Zip Code");
   zipCode = Integer.parseInt(input);
   zipCode = (char)zipCode;

    //getting zipCode - now gives zipCode a CHAR value, which I can use to compare.
   zipCode2 = ((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Re-Type Zip Code")).charAt(0);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Zip Code: " + zipCode2);

//===================================================================================   

   //Display weight, height, lenth, width |||| DEBUG
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is your input" + "\n" + weight + "\n" + width + "\n" + height + "\n" + length + "\n" + "Zip Code: " +zipCode);

   //getting total dimensions
   totalDimen = (length * width * height) + weight;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Dimensions:\n" + totalDimen); //DEBUG
//====================================================================================   

   //if weight is <= 5 pounds, shipping = $12.00
   if ( weight <= 5 )
   {
      shipping = 12;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost12);
   }

   //if weight is > 5 pounds and <= 15 pounds, shipping = $14.00 
   if ( weight > 5 && weight <= 15 )
   {
      shipping = 14;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost14);
   }

   //if weight is > 15 pounds and <= 34 pounds, shipping = $17.00
   if ( weight > 15 && weight <= 34 )
   {
      shipping = 17;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost17);
   }

   //if weigth is > 34 pounds and <= 45 pounds, shipping = $21.00
   if ( weight > 34 && weight <= 45 )
   {
      shipping = 21;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost21);
   }

   //if weigth is > 45 pounds and <= 60 pounds, shipping = $33.00
   if ( weight > 45 && weight <= 60 )
   {
      shipping = 33;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost33);
   }

   //if weigth is > 60 pounds, shipping = $105.00
   if ( weight > 60 )
   {
      shipping = 105;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost105);
   }
//====================================================================================   

   //applying the surcharge using zip code
   if ( zipCode2 == 4 )
   {
      surcharge = (shipping * .05);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 5% is: $" + surcharge);
   }
   else if ( zipCode2 == 9 )
   {
      surcharge = (shipping * .09);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 9% is: $" + surcharge);
   }
   else
   {
      surcharge = (shipping * .14);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 14% is: $" + surcharge);
   }
//====================================================================================   

   //if the zip code is even, + 2% additional surcharge fee 


 }
}
```

This is the output error:

```
Assignment3.java:122: error: variable shipping might not have been initialized
      surcharge = (shipping * .05);
                   ^
Assignment3.java:127: error: variable shipping might not have been initialized
      surcharge = (shipping * .09);
                   ^
Assignment3.java:132: error: variable shipping might not have been initialized
      surcharge = (shipping * .14);
```

What can I do to fix this? I want it to go to the if statement, grab the shipping variable, then go down to the next if statement where it decides the surcharge rate based on the Zip code.

I did some tweeking while typing this:
I don't know if it's better, but it works differently. Now it doesn't do the surcharge correctly.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Assignment3 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   double width;
   double length;
   double height;
   double weight;
   double totalDimen;         // (width * length * height) + weight
   double shipping;
   double totalCost;
   double cost12 = 12;
   double cost14 = 14;
   double cost17 = 17;
   double cost21 = 21;
   double cost33 = 33;
   double cost105 = 105;
   double surcharge;
   int zipCode;               //gets the zip code
   char zipCode2;

   String input;

   //changing the decimal format
   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");


   //getting weight
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total weight");
   weight = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting height
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total height");
   height = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting length
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total length");
   length = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting width
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the total width");
   width = Double.parseDouble(input);

   //getting zipCode
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Zip Code");
   zipCode = Integer.parseInt(input);
   zipCode = (char)zipCode;

    //getting zipCode - now gives zipCode a CHAR value, which I can use to compare.
   zipCode2 = ((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Re-Type Zip Code")).charAt(0);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Zip Code: " + zipCode2);

//===================================================================================   

   //Display weight, height, lenth, width |||| DEBUG
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is your input" + "\n" + weight + "\n" + width + "\n" + height + "\n" + length + "\n" + "Zip Code: " +zipCode);

   //getting total dimensions
   totalDimen = (length * width * height) + weight;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Dimensions:\n" + totalDimen); //DEBUG
//====================================================================================   

   //if weight is <= 5 pounds, shipping = $12.00
   if ( weight <= 5 )
   {
      shipping = 12;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost12);
   }

   //if weight is > 5 pounds and <= 15 pounds, shipping = $14.00 
   if ( weight > 5 && weight <= 15 )
   {
      shipping = 14;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost14);
   }

   //if weight is > 15 pounds and <= 34 pounds, shipping = $17.00
   else if ( weight > 15 && weight <= 34 )
   {
      shipping = 17;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost17);
   }

   //if weigth is > 34 pounds and <= 45 pounds, shipping = $21.00
   else if ( weight > 34 && weight <= 45 )
   {
      shipping = 21;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost21);
   }

   //if weigth is > 45 pounds and <= 60 pounds, shipping = $33.00
   else if ( weight > 45 && weight <= 60 )
   {
      shipping = 33;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost33);
   }

   //if weigth is > 60 pounds, shipping = $105.00
   else 
   {
      shipping = 105;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Shipping is: " + cost105);
   }
//====================================================================================   

   //applying the surcharge using zip code
   if ( zipCode2 == 4 )
   {
      surcharge = (shipping * .05);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 5% is: $" + surcharge);
   }
   else if ( zipCode2 == 9 )
   {
      surcharge = (shipping * .09);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 9% is: $" + surcharge);
   }
   else
   {
      surcharge = (shipping * .14);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 14% is: $" + surcharge);
   }


//====================================================================================   

   //if the zip code is even, + 2% additional surcharge fee 


 }
}
```

Comment: Weird - they are primitives so I would've thought they had a default value, but just make all of them equal to zero and that should fix it.

Comment: can you please edit the code so I know exactly what you mean?

Comment: When you declare all the variables (e.g. `double shipping;`), rename it to `double shipping = 0;`.

Comment: What is the value printed for "Shipping is: $" ?

Comment: okay I will give it a try

Comment: @Zizouz212 local variables don't have default values, fields do.

Comment: @Ascalonian it's supposed to print the surcharge which is (shipping cost * percentage)

Comment: @Pshemo Fields as in instance or method variables?

Comment: Oh, stupid me :/ Didn't realize that was in a main method...

Comment: @ChrisZog you are initializing your `shipping` only in `if` blocks, but compiler can't be sure that at least one of these blocks will be executed which leaves possibility that `shipping` will not be initialized and that may be is dangerous which is why you are seeing this error.

Comment: @Pshemo so what can I change to get this to work?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Fields are variables which belong to class/instance that's all. Which means that methods doesn't have fields but (local) variables.

Comment: @ChrisZog  Have you stepped through it using the debugger in your IDE? Put in breakpoints and watch the variable values.

Comment: @ChrisZog "so what can I change to get this to work" it depends on what you want to achieve. If your variable should be used in sum you can initialize it with 0, if with multiplication then you can initialize it with 1. I didn't read your whole code and don't know what your code is suppose do to so it is hard to tell exactly what you need.

Comment: i added set :
double shipping = 0
but it still doesn't work. I am not getting an error anymore. The last if statement doesn't work though with it.

Comment: Anyway your question looks like it contains a lot of code which is unrelated to the problem you are facing. Could you [edit] it and limit to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your comparisons in the "surcharge" if/else block to compare the value entered against a character value (whereas right now you're comparing to an int value).

```
    // applying the surcharge using zip code
    if (zipCode2 == '4') {
        surcharge = (shipping * .05);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 5% is: $" + surcharge);
    } else if (zipCode2 == '9') {
        surcharge = (shipping * .09);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 9% is: $" + surcharge);
    } else {
        surcharge = (shipping * .14);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your surcharge cost at 14% is: $" + surcharge);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the local variable `double shipping;` with a value. In your code if all the conditions where `shipping` is assigned a value doesn't hold true, and you reach the point where you calculate `surcharge` using `shipping` value, then `shipping` doesn't have a value and since its a local variable the compiler makes sure it is assigned before being accessed.

Assign a value: `double shipping = 0.0;`

Comment: still gives me the output of 14% even though the zip code is 4 which should display the 5% expression.

Comment: @ChrisZog thats because `zipCode2` is a `char` but you are comparing it with `int` value so it always goes into the `else` block. You might want to do `if ( zipCode2 == '4' )`

Comment: ooooh so i should do 
'4'
'9'

Comment: @ChrisZog your question was about something else though.

Answer (score 0):

From the initial code you just change change

```
double shipping = 0;
```

You cannot use a local variable with out initializing

Comment: I did that, but when it calculates the surcharge (shipping cost * percentage) it just gives the last value of 14%. which isn't what I want. If I enter the zip code of "4" it should do the if statement of .05

Comment: its problem with your zip2 checking .. its  a char so you need to be checking '4' or ASCII value of it you are doing integer comparison